# Automatically "continue" a comment block in Sublime when pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, comments, sublimetext2

I'm sure there's an answer out there but due to the ambiguity of this question and keywords it's difficult.

All I want is a commenting plugin or answer to mimic Java in Eclipse where:

```
/* 
 * This is a description of a function in Javascript
 * When I press return a line like this
 *
 * should appear (above) and allow me to continue the comment block
 * and be surrounded by the following
 */
```

**UPDATE/ANSWER**

A few minutes after I posted this user pst came in and rephrased my question to actually make sense. After searching I found DocBlockr. Works great, thank you both!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start with the DocBlockr package.

If you enter and align the first `*` it will insert the following starting `*`s.

```
/*
 * <-- Type and align that one, hit <RETURN>...
 * <-- This one will be inserted and aligned automatically.
```

If you insert a double-asterisk it will insert the leading `*`s without the hinting:

```
/**
 * <-- Inserted automatically.
```

If you're at the start of a function it'll put the JsDoc stuff in for you as well.